# Retrieve specific object in a file

Tags: javascript

I've got a file.txt with different information like this:

```
"toto": "1.0",
"tata": "2.0",
"titi": "1.2",
"trtr": "2.4"
```

I want to do a list with only the name of project, like this:

```
toto
tata
titi
trtr
```

But I don't know how to do this in JS ? Need to parse my file ?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `const toto = {...}` to your file and give it a .js extension, you can include it in the page:

The file would look like this

```
const toto = { "toto": "1.0",
               "tata": "2.0",
               "titi": "1.2",
               "trtr": "2.4"}
```

and the script in the page

```
<script src="toto.js"></script>
<script>
const list = Object.keys(toto);
console.log(list);
</script>
```

```js
const toto = {
  "toto": "1.0",
  "tata": "2.0",
  "titi": "1.2",
  "trtr": "2.4"
}

const list = Object.keys(toto);
console.log(list);
```

---

---

Alternatively Ajax the file using fetch and wrap the text in `{}` before using JSON.parse:

```
fetch('http://localhost/toto.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then((data) => {
    const list = Object.keys(JSON.parse("{"+data+"}"))
    console.log(list)
  })
```

```js
const fileContent = `"toto": "1.0",
"tata": "2.0",
"titi": "1.2",
"trtr": "2.4"` 

const list = Object.keys(JSON.parse("{"+fileContent+"}"))
console.log(list)
```